# Azure functions & HTTP OPTIONS request

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want an existing application (which I do not control) to send information to an Azure function.

The application first sends a HTTP OPTIONS request, and will then regularly send HTTP POST messages.

The problem I have is that the application expects a header "Allow : POST,OPTIONS" in the response from the Azure function on the OPTIONS request. If the header is not present, it will not continue (instead, it throws an error : 'POST is not allowed')

When trying to set the header in Azure functions, I get the following error message

`System.Net.Http: Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.`

I did enable CORS for all locations, and allowed all methods in the configuration.

```js
module.exports = function (context, req) 
{
    //context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.method == "OPTIONS") 
    {
            context.res = 
            {
                body: "",
                headers: 
                { 
                    //"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "POST,OPTIONS",
                    "allow" : "POST,OPTIONS"
                },
                status: 200,
            };
    }
    context.done();
}
```

The specification say that the Allow header should be set for a 405 response. If the header is empty, nothing is allowed. However, there is no logic defined for when the header is not present at all.

Is there a method through which I can send this header in response to the HTTP OPTIONS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is expected. Function runtime is based on C#, when the response tries to add the `Allow` header, underlying C# code checks its name. It's by design that `Allow` is a read-only header in [HttpContentHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties) hence we can't add it in [HttpResponseHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpresponseheaders?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Here are two workarounds for you to refer.

1. Use a custom header name like `Allow-Method`.
2. Create a new Function app, it uses Function runtime 2.0 by default, where we can set `Allow` header.

Comment: I have now following settings :

FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~2
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=node
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=10.14.1

after update, I get an error "Error:

The function runtime is unable to start."

Comment: Thanks for the tip !!!
Azure does not allow for upgrading if there are existing functions. Creating a new one did the trick
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version

Comment: @Kermit754 You are right, it's safer to create a new one. The steps work for me as I only have one function like your sample above. Could you accept my suggestion if it did some help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing this through the portal, navigate to the `integrate` section of the function and select POST and OPTIONS methods.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it through putting an APIM in front of teh logic app. This APIM just returns a 200 in case of the OPTIONS request, and calls the logic app for the subsequent HTTP post requests

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the allowed methods to the **function.json** files as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---configuration)?

Example below:

```
   "authLevel": "anonymous",
   "type": "httpTrigger",
   "direction": "in",
   "name": "req",
   "methods": [
    "post",
    "options"
   ]
```

Comment: Hello, yes I have these set properly  
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post",
        "options"
      ]
    },